# HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'ST' not supported

Tags: java, swift, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot in my server. I have an method to call like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@PostMapping(path = "/checkLoginMobile")
public ResponseEntity<UserAccountRespone> loginMobile(@RequestBody String account) throws ParseException {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(account);
    String username = json.get("username").toString();
    String password = json.get("password").toString();
    UserAccount userAccount = userAccountRepository.login(username, password);
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.getUserProfile(username);

    if (userAccount != null) {
        UserAccountRespone userAccountRespone = new UserAccountRespone(username, userProfile.getFullname(),
                userProfile.getBirth(), userProfile.getAddress(), userProfile.getCity(), userProfile.getEmail(),
                userProfile.getPhone(), userProfile.getSexual(), userProfile.getCreatedAt(),
                userProfile.getUpdatedAt(), userAccount.getRole().getId(), userAccount.getRole().getName());

        return new ResponseEntity<UserAccountRespone>(userAccountRespone, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserAccountRespone>(new UserAccountRespone(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have two method from mobile to call api server (using Swift 4). This is the first method:

```
func login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: UserProfile?) -> ()){
    var _userProfile:UserProfile?
    let url = BASE_URL + "checkLoginMobile"
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        debugPrint(response)
        print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

                _userProfile = UserProfile(username: json["username"].string!,
                                           fullname: json["fullname"].string!,
                                           birth: json["birth"].int!,
                                           address:json["address"].string!,
                                           city:json["city"].string!,
                                           email:json["email"].string!,
                                           phone:json["phone"].string!,
                                           roleId:json["roleId"].int!,
                                           roleName:json["roleName"].string!,
                                           sexual:json["sexual"].int!,
                                           createdAt:json["createdAt"].int!,
                                           updatedAt:json["updatedAt"].int!)
                completion(_userProfile)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And the second method:

```
func getAllModels(completion: @escaping (_ result: [String]?) -> ()) {
    var _modelList:[String] = []
    let url = BASE_URL + "getAllProductAndModelv2"
    Alamofire.request(url, method:.get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
                do {
                    if let data = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as? [String: Any], let models = json["all"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for model in models {
                            if let name = model["link"] as? String {
                                _modelList.append(name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("error")
                }
                completion(_modelList)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The flow is first I run `getAllModel()` method from mobile and it will call `loginMobile()` api from server. Next that I run `login()` method from mobile and it will call `loginMobile()` api from server.
The error cause when my mobile application call `login()` method, the app crash and the server return an error:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'ST' not supported
```

I don't know why the method 'POST' become 'ST' method...
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can we see the calling code? Does this work if you call this manually with Curl?

Comment: why not create request as object rather than @RequestBody String account. that will remove this problem.

Comment: @Todd I were edit the post with mobile calling code

Comment: How did you solved this problem?